# use mapSqlParameterSource in dynamic queries

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am using `Spring MVC` and `JDBC` template to fetch data from `PostgreSQL` db and I am using a dynamic query like this and filling the query like this:

```
Select * from users where name=:name and class=:class;
```

Now in the above query the name and class will be filled when we receive a value for them by frontend using params. Now suppose I only want the data to be filtered through name and not class then I do this:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("name", request.params.name);
//run the query
```

But as we can see we don't have class in my request params so I cant put class in there and the query becomes wrong and gives an error.

How to handle this kinda scenario where we define the query once and assign variables dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

We use jpa/hibernate + querydsl tool. And we can dynamic change sqlstatement if parameter is null or not. Like this (with QueryDsl):

```
if (param!= null) {
  query.where(dt.myColumn.eq(param));
} else {
  query.where(dt.myColumn.isNull());
}
```

(without QueryDsl):

```
String query = "Select * from users where ";

if (param != null) {
  query += "name = :name";
}
```

But You must pay attention To "WHERE" and "AND" clauses!

You can use hibernate Criteria Api too.